# MPEG-DASH server 405 error PUT is not allowed for the URL /dash/dash.m4s

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php5

I am trying to build an MPEG-DASH server on Ubuntu 16.04. I installed Apache and PHP, but each time I am trying to put files inside the folder dedicated for the segments coming from the encoder, I receive the error:  The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /dash/

I added this to the /etc/apache2/mods-available/userdir.conf file and also to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file. But the issue is still there :

```
   <Directory /var/www/html/dash/>
            AllowOverride All
            <Limit GET POST PUT HEAD OPTIONS>
                    Require all granted
            </Limit>
            <LimitExcept GET POST PUT HEAD OPTIONS>
                    Require all denied
            </LimitExcept>
    </Directory>
```

What I cannot see, is the fact that maybe i need authentication somewhere to allow files to be put on the apache server ? I am pretty new with apache so I am trying to understand how the PUT method actually works.

To mention is that both the encoder and the apache server are on the same subnet.

Any ideas ?
Thanks !

Comment: You need to map the request to a PHP file that handles the `PUT` method for you, the core Apache modules do not implement `PUT` (except maybe the DAV modules). Exactly how depends on your individual requirements, but there is an example in this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/148865/enable-put-method-on-apache-for-any-php-script You don't really need those limit blocks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I took a look on that post and also the link posted there about that voodoo :)) but unfortunately i do not have .htaccess on my server. Do I need to create that ? I managed to run a2enmod actions and a2enmod rewrite succesfully, restarted apache, but still no luck. Also i do have apache2.conf and not hhtpd.conf (presume is for the old apache server). Any other thoughts ?

Comment: No you don't need htaccess files. They are *never* needed if you have access to modify the main configuration files and can restart Apache. Apache has no facility to upload files built into it, so unless *you* provide some software that handles the `PUT` method, it will simply not work. There is no generic `handle PUT method` script.